# Convert if statement to case of in pascal?

Tags: pascal

Im using pascal, can u convert this code statement to case of ? In pascal ?
This my program on pascal, if statement to case of.

Thankyou very much

```
TYPE
        MHS = record
        nama1,nama2:string;
        ipk1,ipk2:longint;
        nim1,nim2:integer;
end;
var
        DataMhs : MHS;
Begin

    clrscr;
    write('Masukan Nama Mahasiswa 1 : ');
    readln(DataMhs.nama1);
    write('Masukan NIM Mahasiswa 1 : ');
    readln(DataMhs.nim1);
    write('Masukan IPK Mahasiswa 1 : ');
    readln(DataMhs.ipk1);

    write('Masukan Nama Mahasiswa 2 : ');
    readln(DataMhs.nama2);
    write('Masukan NIM Mahasiswa 2 : ');
    readln(DataMhs.nim2);
    write('Masukan IPK Mahasiswa 2 : ');
    readln(DataMhs.ipk2);

    if DataMhs.ipk1 > DataMhs.ipk2 then
        write('IPK ',DataMhs.nama1,'Lebih besar')
    else if DataMhs.ipk2 > DataMhs.ipk1 then
        write('IPK ',DataMhs.nama2,'Lebih besar')
    else
        write('IPK ',DataMhs.nama1,' dengan ',DataMhs.ipk2,' SAMA');

    readln;
end.
```

I dont know how to convert it, please help. Haha

Comment: Why do you want to make it a `case` statement? (Which as has been pointed out, isn't appropriate for the conditions you're testing, but rather applies to discrete values or ranges of values.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* that what you have in mind might be something like the following:

```pascal
type
  TCompareResult = (cmpLeftGreater, cmpRightGreater, cmpEqual);

case CompareInts(DataMhs.ipk1, DataMhs.ipk2) of
  cmpLeftGreater:
    write('IPK ', DataMhs.nama1, 'Lebih besar');
  cmpRightGreater:
    write('IPK ', DataMhs.nama2, 'Lebih besar');
  else {cmpEqual}
    write('IPK ', DataMhs.nama1, ' dengan ', DataMhs.ipk2, ' SAMA');
end;
```

However, you still need to implement this `CompareInts` function, and it will still need to use the same conditional structure you already have in your original code:

```pascal
function CompareInts(left, right: Integer): TCompareResult;
begin
  if left > right then
    Result := cmpLeftGreater
  else if right > left then
    Result := cmpRightGreater
  else
    Result := cmpEqual;
end;
```

Thus, the function doesn't really gain you much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make you code **better looking**, then you can use that -->

```
with DataMhs do
 begin
      if ipk1 > ipk2 then write('IPK ',DataMhs.nama1,'Lebih besar');
      else if ipk1 < ipk2 then write('IPK ',DataMhs.nama2,'Lebih besar');
      else write('IPK ',DataMhs.nama1,' dengan ',DataMhs.ipk2,' SAMA');
 end;
```

But I do not think that the **case**

is useful for that. Because case is used for **known values** such as:

```
case a of
     1: Writeln(' Some code here') ;
     2: Writeln(' Some code here') ;
     3: Writeln(' Some code here') ;
     4: Writeln(' Some code here') ;

     else Writeln(' That is used for other values. ');
end;
```

**Case cannot be used for that kind of problem.**